# Howto check if first 6 position in received file match on first line or second line in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I want to check in groovy if the first 6 characters on line 1 or line 2 match the text 'ABCDEFG'. How will I do this in Groovy?

```
def testfile = '''
FEDCBAAVM654321
ABCDEFMVA123456
'''

if ( testfile[0..6].equals("ABCDEF") ) {
    // First line starts with ABCDEF
}

if ( testfile.tokenize("\n").get(1)[0..6].equals("ABCDEF") ) {
    // Second line starts with ABCDEF
}
```

It should be something like above or the test may be done in one line if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
def testfile = '''FEDCBAAVM654321
                 |ABCDEFMVA123456
                 '''.stripMargin()

testfile.tokenize( '\n' )                     // split on newline
        .take( 2 )                            // take the first two lines
        .every { it.startsWith( 'ABCDEF' ) }  // true if both start with ABCDEF
```

or

```
testfile.tokenize( '\n' )                  // split on newline
        .take( 2 )                         // take the first two lines
        .any { it.startsWith( 'ABCDEF' ) } // true if either or both start ABCDEF
```

Comment: In your solution you say 'true if both start with ABCDEF'. But I want it to be true if line 1 or line 2 matches ABCDEF. Would this pass also? Or only pass if both lines start with ABCDEF?

Comment: @markdark ahhh sorry, added a second method using `any` which will be true if either (or both) lines start with ABCDEF :-)